# I have a problem with json codes of .glb file

Tags: three.js, blender, react-three-fiber

I use Blender to create a simple model with a simple animation ; but when I export the model as (gltf/glb) and when I drag and drop the exported glb file in code editor(VScode) ;I can not see the json code of my model and here is the ERROR (  this file is not displayed in the text editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding ). i need to use the animation of my model like this : https://projector-night-room.vercel.app/

but i can upload the model on web but i need to see the json code of my model .